# Storing 100+ Objects in Node.js "global" variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

My configuration settings are dynamic, so I decided to save them in a database.  These configurations are classified by the `NODE_ENV`, so I want to bootstrap the configuration by querying the database once the server starts, because of the necessity of having the configuration for every request.  So, I keep the configuration in a global object.

My questions are:

1. Is this feasible approach?
2. Is there any way to bootstrap the configuration?
3. Will storing this object lead to a memory leak?
4. How much space will it take to store the configuration in a global?
5. Will the global objects be garbage collected?

Comment: No, global objects are not garbage-collected, but they don't "leak" because you're not creating many of them that would accumulate over time.

Comment: Will this increase my memory tremendously ? Think of 100 objects which may have at least 3 keys and value pair's and I am storing all in global.

Comment: No more than storing them locally. 100 objects is negligible. Measure it yourself, but I guess it's not taking more than 1MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is definitely feasible.  However, I don't know the context of your application, so I can't say if it would be good.
2. In order to load the configuration, you'd have to connect to the database and perform the load before you attempted to access it.  Doing this would be dependent on your application, but you can always connect to the database before you give up control to the application.  Then, it would be a simple matter of picking the global name to store it in, and store it in the global.
3. No.  Not unless you keep creating objects over and over again uncontrollably, and somehow have them referenced from some object that is in scope somewhere, which is extremely difficult to do without noticing.
4. Honestly?  Not much.  The standard library of node.js is probably much bigger than your configuration.  Hell, probably the library you'd be using to connect to the database to get your configuration would be bigger than your configuration.
5. No.  Not as long as you are able to access it.  Node.JS uses a heavily modified mark-and-sweep garbage collector; this means that Node.JS has a list of objects that are *never, ever* garbage collected (the "roots"), and marks every object it can access from these objects.  Anything not marked is collected, and freed.  The global namespace is one of these roots, meaning anything that the global namespace references is not collected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will this would make my application dependent ?, Consider that, before binding to the port(server start), i am going to connect to the database and query it, and save that object in global.

Comment: For the "3rd" answer i will refer that global variable in many places, think the global config would be {"clientId":"aaaa","key":"hehe"} & my application  is going to act as proxy, so i will use that clientId in all those proxy services. Will this lead to memory leak? Just want to clear my thoughts around it, before implementing this my code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.